# Múltiples redirecciones en htaccess

Tags: apache

En el htaccess raíz de mi host compartido, tengo múltiples redirecciones pero en ocasiones no matchea con algunas reglas.

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# (1) Redireccionamos el contenido de /ar a /int
RewriteRule ^ar/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/int/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

# (2) SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

# (3) no www a www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

**Ejemplos:**

1. La página `https://www.ejemplo.com/int/index.php` existe, pero si accedo a `https://www.ejemplo.com/ar/index.php` (no existe el subdirectorio /ar), no matchea con la regla (1) y me devuelve un error 404, es decir que no redirige a /int.
2. `ejemplo.com` => `https://ejemplo.com`: Matchea con la regla (2) y redirige, pero luego no matchea con la regla (3)
3. `https://ejemplo.com` => `https://ejemplo.com`: No matchea con la regla (3)
4. `www.ejemplo.com` => `https://www.ejemplo.com`: Matchea con la regla (2)

He probado y leído mucha documentación, pero no he podido solucionarlo.

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: Yo no le encuentro ningún error. Sin embargo, es un peligro estar probando con `R=301`, siempre deberías probar con `R=302` o `R=307` y estar muy seguro antes de setear un 301. Por tu descripción, me animaría a decir que el problema no está en el `.htaccess`, sino que se debe a alguna regla que hayas intentado momentáneamente y haya quedado en el caché de tu navegador. Si es sólo en tu navegador, no hay problema. Si hay usuarios en el medio, el panorama no es bueno. Nota de color: [301 Redirects: The Horror That Cannot Be Uncached](http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/)

Comment: Por otro lado, como comentario, deberías invertir las reglas: primero el `www` y luego el `https`

Comment: Muchas gracias Mariano por la respuesta, estoy utilizando la redirección permanente (301) porque el sitio está en producción, pero no logro hacer que funcione.
Estoy pensando seriamente que el problema está del lado del host, pero como es un host compartido, no puedo ver la configuración de Apache.

Comment: Justamente, si está en producción, más motivos para no hacer una redirección permanente hasta que esté funcionando y testeado... Una redirección permanente queda chacheada en los navegadores (y en muchos casos no caduca)... Como te dije, no veo nada mal, salvo que tu navegador (y el de todos los que hayan pasado por esa redirección) ya lo tengan cacheado.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mariano por las sugerencias y la nota de color, muy interesante.

Te cuento que lo solucioné pero fue medio raro lo que pasó.

Editando desde un editor online desde cPanel, comenzó de repente a funcionar. El archivo editado desde mi PC y transferido con FileZilla no matchaba las reglas, pero si lo editaba desde el propio host (tan solo agregar un caracter en un comentario), funcionaba.

Pensé que era el encoding pero no, también configuré FileZilla para transferencia binaria únicamente, pero tampoco.

Calculo que debe tener que ver con el **CR LF** ya que tengo Windows.

Comment: ja! Qué raro! Es la primera vez que escucho un problema así... De hecho yo tengo CRLF en el .htaccess y funciona sin problemas (y no tengo idea qué opción configura los saltos de línea)... Me alegro que lo hayas solucionado.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mariano, te cuento que probé editarlo desde un Debian y funcionó sin problema, por lo que seguramente el problema estaba en los saltos de línea.

Ambos archivos (el que funcionaba y el que no) estaban codificados en UTF-8 sin BOM, la única diferencia entre ellos era que, el que no funcionaba tiene **CR** como salto de línea, mientras el que funcionaba tiene **LR**.
Deduzco que ese debe haber sido el problema, otra cosa no se me ocurre.
Gracias por los tips y tu tiempo!